# Hot deployment using mod_wsgi,python and django on Apache

Tags: python, django, apache2, mod-wsgi, hotdeploy

I have setup an Apache server with mod_wsgi, python_sql, mysql and django.
Everything works fine, except the fact that if I make some code changes, they do not reflect immidiately, though I thing that everything is compiled on the fly when it comes to python/mod_wsgi.

I have to shut down the server and come back again to see the changes.

Can someone point me to how hot-deployment can be achieved with the above setup??

Thanks,

Neeraj

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is covered by mod_wsgi documentation. See:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ReloadingSourceCode

Answer (score 3):

Just touching the wsgi file allways worked for me.

Comment: That only causes whole process to be reloaded when daemon mode is used. So, do that with embedded mode and it will not have the desired affect.